# How to properly use forwardRef in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm very new to React, please bear with me

I have a component

```
const Avatar = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const {
    color,
    className,
    size,
    tag: Tag,
    ...rest
  } = props

  return (
    <Tag
      className={classnames('avatar', {
        [className]: className,
        [`bg-${color}`]: color,
        [`avatar-${size}`]: size
      })}
      ref={ref}
      {...rest}
    >
      ... //rest of codes
    </Tag>
  )
})

export default Avatar
```

Now, I can do this in `javascript`

```
<Avatar size="sm" color="success" />
```

However, in Typescript I will be getting error message

```
Property 'size' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'
```

Any idea what went wrong? I assume I need to pass `ref` so I do

```
const ref = React.createRef<Tag>();
<Avatar ref={ref} size="sm" color="success" />
```

But I still have same issue, how do I pass `size` and `color` as props? I tried looking for answer around the internet and SO but I can't seem to find a solution, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: props cant be use as JSX. This piece of code `<Tag> . . . </Tag>` is invalid. You pass Tag as props you should import it instead.

Answer (score 1):

putting forwardRef on the export solves TSLint errors

```
const Avatar = (props, ref) => {
const {
 color,
 className,
 size,
 tag: Tag,
 ...rest
} = props

return (
  <Tag
  className={classnames('avatar', {
    [className]: className,
    [`bg-${color}`]: color,
    [`avatar-${size}`]: size
  })}
  ref={ref}
  {...rest}
  >
  ... //rest of codes
  </Tag>
 )
}

export default forwardRef(Avatar)
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. However, could you explain why this fixes the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you really need to forward ref or not. I hope my answer would give you some way to solve your use case. I can see that you pass `Tag` as a prop and you use it as JSX tag which is invalid.

Bare with me this piece of JSX code is invalid

```
<Tag
  className={classnames('avatar', {
    [className]: className,
    [`bg-${color}`]: color,
    [`avatar-${size}`]: size
  })}
  ref={ref}
  {...rest}
>
  ... //rest of codes
</Tag>
```

because you pass `Tag` as prop you cannot use it as JSX tag. You can pass a JSX tag as props but the implementation is not that way. You should import that tag instead or If you really want to pass it as prop. you need to compose it on its parent component.

**Like this**

```
const ParentComponent: React.FC = () => (
  <Avatar
    // You have to compose it here

    tag={
      <Tag
      // className={classnames('avatar', {
      //   [className]: className,
      //   [`bg-${color}`]: color,
      //   [`avatar-${size}`]: size
      // })}
      // ref={ref}
      // {...rest}
      >
        ... //rest of codes
      </Tag>
    }
  />
);

export default ParentComponent;
```

You may also interact the demo in codesandbox so you may get more Idea of what I'm trying to say. Just click it **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-breeze-46bw8?file=/src/App.tsx)**